# iOS Push Notifications Only Received By Development Devices

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an application which sends some push notifications, actually everything works like a charm and push notifications are received by my devices without any problem.

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8164-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started) to while development and used `pushok` library to develop server side.

But I realized that none of my notifications are received by other devices; only the devices which I registered as development devices receive them.

`Device tokens` are correct, either running application via USB from Xcode or installing from AppStore give the same token but it works only my devices.

Do you have an idea?

**UPDATE**

I am using Auth Token for APNS, instead of certificate based authentication so there is no production or sandbox option. But still i can not receive other than development devices.

Comment: If the below answer solved your issue, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem; as mentioned in the update section of question i was not using certificate based APNS so sandbox or production certificates were not the problem. I was using Auth Token Key for APNS and there isn't any difference between sandbox or production.

Besides `pushok` library has a flag for production or sandbox which i missed and forgot in sandbox. When i recheck documentation for pushok i saw the code below

```
$client = new Client($authProvider, $production = false);
```

Changing to `$production = true` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you are using correct APNS certificates for different configurations.

Apps running in development devices will be in debug configuration and its APNS cert will be pointing to **gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com**

Appstore will be in release configuration and its APNS cert will be pointing to **gateway.push.apple.com** and not the sandboxed one.

So, please check your certificates.

[NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) is an excellent tool for testing Push notifications using just cert and deviceTokens without any code. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Sorry i have to remove correct answer mark because if you check the article i mentioned i am not using certificate based authentication. I am using Auth Token so there is no production or sandbox option.

Comment: Don't feel sorry. No issues. :-)